# grid of divs width not lining up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up a grid of divs to make like a 15 min gant chart for scheduling tasks for a day. The first div on both I set the width to 200px but why is the one with "Task" in it bigger?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .header { 
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-right: 1px;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .line-item{
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: cadetblue;
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Daily Planner</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="display: flex; margin: 0px;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="header">8:00</div>
        <div class="header">8:15</div>
        <div class="header">8:30</div>
        <div class="header">8:45</div>
        <div class="header">9:00</div>
        <div class="header">9:15</div>
        <div class="header">9:30</div>
        <div class="header">9:45</div>
        <div class="header">10:00</div>
        <div class="header">10:15</div>
        <div class="header">10:30</div>
        <div class="header">10:45</div>
        <div class="header">11:00</div>
        <div class="header">11:15</div>
        <div class="header">11:30</div>
        <div class="header">11:45</div>
        <div class="header">12:00</div>
        <div class="header">12:15</div>
        <div class="header">12:30</div>
        <div class="header">12:45</div>
        <div class="header">1:00</div>
        <div class="header">1:15</div>
        <div class="header">1:30</div>
        <div class="header">1:45</div>
        <div class="header">2:00</div>
        <div class="header">2:15</div>
        <div class="header">2:30</div>
        <div class="header">2:45</div>
        <div class="header">3:00</div>
        <div class="header">3:15</div>
        <div class="header">3:30</div>
        <div class="header">3:45</div>
        <div class="header">4:00</div>
        <div class="header">4:15</div>
        <div class="header">4:30</div>
        <div class="header">4:45</div>
        <div class="header">5:00</div>
        <div class="header">5:15</div>
        <div class="header">5:30</div>
        <div class="header">5:45</div>
        <div class="header">6:00</div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; margin: 0px;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; background-color: red;">Task 1</div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your containers are set to `display: flex;` but you have not set any flex css on the children.
Setting `flex-shrink: 0;` will make sure they are always 200px.

[THIS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is probably the best guide for flexbox

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        .header { 
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-right: 1px;
            width: 50px;
        }
        .line-item{
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: cadetblue;
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Daily Planner</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="display: flex; margin: 0px;">
        <div style="flex-shrink: 0; display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="header">8:00</div>
        <div class="header">8:15</div>
        <div class="header">8:30</div>
        <div class="header">8:45</div>
        <div class="header">9:00</div>
        <div class="header">9:15</div>
        <div class="header">9:30</div>
        <div class="header">9:45</div>
        <div class="header">10:00</div>
        <div class="header">10:15</div>
        <div class="header">10:30</div>
        <div class="header">10:45</div>
        <div class="header">11:00</div>
        <div class="header">11:15</div>
        <div class="header">11:30</div>
        <div class="header">11:45</div>
        <div class="header">12:00</div>
        <div class="header">12:15</div>
        <div class="header">12:30</div>
        <div class="header">12:45</div>
        <div class="header">1:00</div>
        <div class="header">1:15</div>
        <div class="header">1:30</div>
        <div class="header">1:45</div>
        <div class="header">2:00</div>
        <div class="header">2:15</div>
        <div class="header">2:30</div>
        <div class="header">2:45</div>
        <div class="header">3:00</div>
        <div class="header">3:15</div>
        <div class="header">3:30</div>
        <div class="header">3:45</div>
        <div class="header">4:00</div>
        <div class="header">4:15</div>
        <div class="header">4:30</div>
        <div class="header">4:45</div>
        <div class="header">5:00</div>
        <div class="header">5:15</div>
        <div class="header">5:30</div>
        <div class="header">5:45</div>
        <div class="header">6:00</div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; margin: 0px;">
            <div style="flex-shrink: 0; display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; width: 200px; background-color: red;">Task 1</div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
            <div class="line-item"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does the blue line not cover each 15 min interval?

Comment: because `background-color:blue;` is only set on the first div in the row. All the others are getting their background color from `.header`